# form action not working in django

Tags: python, django, forms, post, submit

I have django 1.4 and I am following a tutorial which uses an older version of django. Its a simple tutorial which creates a wiki app with Page as model.

The problem is that the view function corresponding to a POST method in a form is not getting invoked.

This is the content in the urls.py:

```
url(r'^wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/edit/$', 'wiki.views.edit_page'),
url(r'^wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/save/$', 'wiki.views.save_page'),
url(r'^wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/$', 'wiki.views.view_page'),
```

This is the content of the template edit.html:

```
<from method = "get" action="/wikicamp/{{page_name}}/save/">
{% csrf_token %}
    <textarea name = "content" rows="20" cols="60">
    {{content}}
    </textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Page"/>
</form>
<a href="/wikicamp/{{page_name}}/save/">this is link to save</a>
```

And this is the content in views.py:

```
def edit_page(request, page_name):
try:
    page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
    content = page.content
except Page.DoesNotExist:
    content = ""
return render_to_response("edit.html", {"page_name":page_name, "content":content}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def save_page(request, page_name):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the page %s." % page_name)
```

I initially I was getting csrf related error and I then tried all the fixes provided in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/casrf/ and followed many many stackoverflow question related to POST and django. Now nothing happens when I click the 'Save Page' button, nothing! Not even any request being sent from the form (Using firebug to track the HTTP request and response)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your HTML: `from` instead of `form`.

You may realize this, but that code won't really save anything. I'm not sure what blog you are following, but you would be better-off following the official Django tutorial in the documentation, then reading the forms docs.

Comment: Oh god kill me!!! Yes that was the mistake.
No, the 'save_page' is a complicated function. To debug, I changed it into something which works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change `method` to `"POST"` in your form.

```
<from method = "get" action="/wikicamp/{{page_name}}/save/">
```

to

```
<form method = "post" action="/wikicamp/{{page_name}}/save/">
```

Comment: You copied his spelling mistakes.

Comment: Actually I was playing around with 'get' and 'post' when it was not working. And yes, the 'form' was the culprit :(. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are some spelling mistakes, such as `from` instead of `form`.
Also the form is malformed.

Change:

```
<a href="/wikicamp/{{page_name}}/save/">this is link to save</a>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Save Page" />
```

And thirdly, change the `method= "get"`to `method="POST"`.

The entire form should look like this

```
<form method = "POST" action="/wikicamp/{{page_name}}/save/">
{% csrf_token %}
    <textarea name = "content" rows="20" cols="60">
    {{content}}
    </textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Page"/>
</form>
```

Also what @DanielRoseman said. But hey, it might come further down the road.

Comment: Thanks limelights, it was the spelling mistake of the 'form'.